# Ideal way to randomly traverse enormous list?

Tags: list

I have an enormous list of numbers (tens of millions), and I want to go through them in a random order without repeats

Is there an effective way to do this in C++, Java, Python?

Comment: You mean you don't want the same number twice in a row or to completely remove duplicates?

Comment: No repeats *by value* or *by index*?

Answer (score 2):

In C++, this might do:

```
std::list<T> foo;
std::vector<T *> bar(foo.size());
std::transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(),
    [](T &a) -> T *
    { 
        return &a;
    });
std::random_shuffle(bar.begin(), bar.end());
for (auto &one_bar: bar)
    do_whatever(*one_bar);
```

Basically, create a vector of the same size and copy pointers to the original list into the vector, then shuffle the vector. Now you can step through and call `do_whatever(T)` on each element in a random order.

Furthermore, if you wish to eliminate duplicate values:

```
std::list<T> foo;
std::vector<T *> bar(foo.size());
std::transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(),
    [](T &a) -> T *
    { 
        return &a;
    });
std::sort(bar.begin(), bar.end(),
    [](T *a, T *b) -> bool
    { 
        return *a > *b; 
    });
std::unique(bar.begin(), bar.end(),
    [](T *a, T *b) -> bool
    { 
        return *a == *b; 
    });
std::random_shuffle(bar.begin(), bar.end());
for (auto &one_bar: bar)
    do_whatever(*one_bar);
```

Assuming your class has these operators defined.

Comment: How does this avoid repeats?

Comment: By definition there are no repeats. See [`std::random_shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/).

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in the link that explains how you don't get repeats. If I have `[1,3,4,2,1,3,4,5,6]` what happens with that?

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer to add removal of duplicates.